# Error in plugin: error getting CPU info: not implemented yet

Tags: influxdb, telegraf

when I tried to run the telegraf, I'm facing this issue. I installed through brew.[command line error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QjvlJ.png)

Using redis server I'm trying to do